# Existing function to slice pandas object by axis number

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to be able to index dynamically by axis, for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=0, index=['row1', 'row2', 'row3'], columns=['col1', 'col2', col3'])
df.index(['row1', 'row3'], axis=0)     # index by rows
df.index(['col1', 'col2'], axis=1)     # index by columns
```

The following function works, but I'm wondering if there's an existing function as I would think it's a common task.

```
def index_axis(df, index, axis):    
    if axis==0: return df.loc[index]
    elif axis==1: return df.loc[:,index]
    elif axis==2: return df.loc[:,:,index]
    else:
        raise ValueError('No axis named {0} for object type {1}'
                         .format(axis, type(df)))
```

For those that are interested, I wanted this function as a helper for the following, that drops rows or columns that contain only zeros.

```
def stripZeros(df, axis=0):
    b = (df != 0).any(axis)
    a2 = (axis+1) % 2
    return index_axis(df, df.axes[a2][b], a2)
```

Comment: Check out `df.T` (and its index). I'm not 100% sure of what you're asking, but that sounds close.

Answer (score 0):

The slice notation here is `:`, meaning all:

```
In [11]: df.loc[['row1', 'row2'], :]
Out[11]:
      col1  col2  col3
row1     0     0     0
row2     0     0     0

In [12]: df.loc[:, ['col1', 'col2']]
Out[12]:
      col1  col2
row1     0     0
row2     0     0
row3     0     0
```

Comment: See my edit: the point is not that I can slice rows or columns, but that I can chose between rows or columns by specifying the axis.

Comment: @Zero python syntax doesn't really lend itself to slicing as a function. Struggling to understand why you'd want this tbh.